# objective c issue

Tags: ios5

I am getting this error 
"No setter method 'setOrgin:' for assignment to property"

```
Rectangle *r =[[Rectangle alloc]init];
XYpoint *p =[[XYpoint alloc]init];
[p setXY : 100 : 300];
[r setWH: 6 : 8];
r.orgin =p;
NSLog(@"Width and height is %i and %i", r.width, r.height);
NSLog(@"Origin is at %i and %i", r.orgin.x, r.orgin.y);
NSLog(@"Area and Peri are %i and %i", [r area], [r perimeter]);
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a typo. You have 'orgin' instead of 'origin' [missing an ' i '] (which I believe is a property on your `Rectangle` class).
Also note that methods like `setXY::` (although they are valid) are considered to be bad programming style in the Objective-C world. A more common pattern for such a method signature would be:

```
setX:andY:
```

but really it's your call...